# Typescript array of objects as props

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```
import React from "react";
import SingleEvent from "./SingleEvent";
interface Item {
  id: string;
  title: string;
  description: string;
  location: string;
  date: string;
  image: string;
  isFeatured: false;
}

export default function EventList({ items }) {
  return (
    <ul>
      {items.map((item: Item) => (
        <SingleEvent key={item.id} />
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}
```

I have this component. Here I destructure the props and get the items array. I do want to define the type of that array.

I tried this

```
function EventList({ items :Item[]})
```

But this seems not working and also the items props can be an empty array as well.

How do I achieve this using TS?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you receive an object as an argument in a function, writing the type information becomes a bit tricky.

You would have to do it like this.

```
export default function EventList({ items }: { items: Item[] }) {
```

This makes the code long and repeating, so I personally recommend making a new interface for the props.

```
interface Props {
  items: Item[]
}

export default function EventList({ items }: Props) {
```

The reason your original code didn't work was because [a colon inside Javascript destructuring means renaming that variable](https://davidwalsh.name/destructuring-alias). That is why Typescript didn't recognize it as type information.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the `props`, and then your destructured variables will infer the type from their object.

So basically, your props can look like this

```
type EventListProps = {
  items: Item[]
}
```

and then your component would be:

```
function EventList(props: EventListProps)
```

which you can also write as

```
function EventList({items}: EventListProps)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try using `Array<T>`, here is an example, it works also with an empty array `[]`

https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-neumann-3hyux

Answer (score -2):

You can try with any as the particular object named items does not exist in your interface. Also no need to loop object. Try this this works.

```
export default function EventList({ item }: any) {
  return (
    <ul>
        <SingleEvent key={item.id} />
    </ul>
  );
}
```